# Wiring colors for 'intermediate' connections

Tags: circuit-design, wiring, wire, breadboard

It seems to that red is the color usually used to connect to the positive terminal and black is usually used to connect to the negative terminal. However, I have seen numerous other colors as 'intermediate' connections. What is a good coloring scheme to use when wiring various (basic) components into a breadboard. For example, here is an example of a circuit I've done below with red meaning direct connection to [+] and blue/black meaning direct connection to [-].

[image]

Comment: I don't colour scheme when using breadboards to be honest. I just use the length that is most convenient regardless of colour.

Comment: Breadboards aren't really meant to be anything more than (very) temporary, so just use whatever makes sense to you. I usually use various colors to go to different buttons/sensors but there is no standard. Just whatever you can keep clear. In the industrial world there are standard colors for things (depending on industry), but not for prototype/breadboards.

Comment: There's no color-coding on breadboards.  The [jumper kits](https://www.jameco.com/z/WJW-60B-R-Wire-Jumper-Kit-350pc-22-AWG-14-Lengths-10-Colors_19290.html) (pre-cut and pre-bent wires) for breadboards are colored by length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over my many years of engineering, I developed a colour scheme for myself that I thought was obvious. However, arguments with other engineers over 'correct' colours have disabused me of the notion that anything is obvious (witness the international mess over mains wiring colours).

FWIW, I use red as +ve, and usually +5v. Black is usually 0v. If I'm running a +3v as well, that tends to get orange (for 3!) or yellow (a sort of unusual red!)

When I need a -5v, it's blue.

When I need +/- higher voltages, like 10, 12 or 15v for opamp rails, then it's orange and purple. I shouldn't have to spell out which of those is +ve and -ve, it should be 'obvious' (is it?). The 0v wire to weave with those from the PSU is green.

'Unusual' supply voltages, and signal voltages get white or yellow, grey or pink.

That's all if I have the colours to hand. If not, I use whatever.

Mains wiring

Here in europe, we have brown as hot, blue as neutral, green/yellow stripes as earth. In the US, they use white, black and green. Other continents use other colours. A report a decade or two ago came up with 'the one true colour scheme' which had to be (a) obvious (b) colour-blind friendly (c) low-light friendly (d) different to all the other existing colour schemes, which is white for hot, grey for neutral and black for ground. I think it's obvious and a great idea, but it's not going to catch on, not least because it would electrocute 90% of americans.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this.  Just use whatever color wire you have available.

For what it's worth, when we have to make changes to a production board, all of the new connections are done with the same color wire, regardless of whether the connection is a signal, power, return, or something else.  White and green seem to be the most used.